# How can I access IBM cloud private CE console management?

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-private

I've installed on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine ICP, cloning the github directory and running the command vagrant up. Just like the README.md  of [this repo](https://github.com/IBM/deploy-ibm-cloud-private/blob/master/docs/deploy-vagrant.md) suggests.
Now I'm trying to access the console management tool via web browser:
The doc says that I only need to type https://master_ip:8443 in my browser.
The first problem is, what do they mean by master_ip? The ip of the master node in the cluster? So, typing ifconfig in the master node's console (after connecting by SSH, vagrant ssh command), i read eth0 : 10.0.2.15.

But, from my host machine, I can neither access the console manager at https://10.0.2.15:8443 nor ping that IP address (100% packet are lost, without any ICMP message).

I got the same result (but with ICMP's 'unreachable host' message) doing the same thing on the IP address I got reading the master's IP in the cluster/hosts file (of the virtual machine).

Moreover, I noticed, typing service --status-all on the master node, that no service seems to be related to the console management tool.

I think I'm confused. :S :S
Thanks in b4.

Comment: Once done you will be able to access the IBM Cloud Private community edition web console here: https://192.168.27.100:8443 (assuming you did not have to change the base_segment value in the Vagrantfile see Conflicting Network Segments section below for details)

Does https://192.168.27.100:8443 work?

Comment: That's exactly what the doc tells me to do. But it doesn't work, the browser tells me that nothing's there. By the way, I didn't even change the base_segment ...